# Google App Maker how to apply custom data validation

Tags: google-app-maker

App Maker has default validations and regular expression validation which will highlight the fields once the error occurs.

We have requirement to do custom validations to check duplicate records in models. Is there any function to check the validation or do we need to do any script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to avoid data duplication will be enforcing 'unique' constraint for your tables using Cloud SQL.

In case you don't want to use Cloud SQL and want to go with **Drive Tables** you can emulate unique constraint manually using locks, queries and model events:

```js
// onCreate model event (actually it is onBeforeCreate)
// this events accepts about-to-create record as parameter
var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
lock.waitLock(5000);

var query = app.models.MyModel.newQuery();
query.filters.SomeField._equals = record.SomeField;

var records = query.run();

if (records.length > 0) {
  throw new Error('Record with SomeField value equal to ' + record.SomeField +
                   ' already exists.');
}

lock.releaseLock();
```

You need `lock` here to prevent other threads concurrently creating records that will violate your unique constraint.

Then you can handle the error on UI in `createItem` function callback:

```js
// create button onClick handler
widget.datasource.createItem({
  success: function(record) {
    // TODO
  },
  failure: function(error) {
    // TODO
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works, But I want to show this message to user in front end below the field.

Comment: I've added client-side part to the answer.

Comment: // create button onClick handler
widget.datasource.createItem({
  success: function(record) {
    // TODO
  },
  failure: function(error) {
    // TODO
  }
}); Is this the code block you are mentioning. I want to show the error message below the control like the required error messages.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/widgets#Widget - look for `validationErrors` property.

Comment: There is not enough documentation for validationErrors property, my server script will throw error so failure function will be called, In that how can I add my error string and show it to the user. Please suggest us some solutions

Comment: There are different ways, to access widget itself (`app.PageName.descendants.WidgetName...`, `app.currentPage.descendants.WidgetName...`, or just `widget` if you are in event handler), but afaik there is only one way to set errors programmatically: `...widget.validationErrors = ['error text here'];`